# Angular 8: ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for TextAreaEditorComponent

Tags: angular

We recently upgraded angular to 8.2.14 The below code was a class which i attempted to convert to a component. I get the following error

ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for TextAreaEditorComponent

Basically the issue is the constructor  .

This was to extend a vendor app SpreadJS

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Input, Optional } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    styleUrls: ['./text-area-editor.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './text-area-editor.component.html'
})
export class TextAreaEditorComponent implements OnInit {
   // @Input() options: any;
    options: any;
    textArea: any;
    containerKeyDownHandler: any;
    containerClickHandler: any;
    maxLength = 500;

    @ViewChild('container', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;

    constructor(
       options: any
    ) {
      this.options = options;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    init(): void {
        const options = this.options;
        const container = options.container;
        this.maxLength = this.options.col.editor.maxLength;

        this.textArea = container.children[0];

        this.textArea.value = options.value;
        this.textArea.focus();

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);

        container.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
        container.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    }

    destroy() {
        const container = this.options.container;
        container.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
        container.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    }

    focus() {
        this.textArea.focus();
    }

    serialize() {
        return this.textArea.value;
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (event.target && event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
            if (event.target.className === 'save') {
                this.options.dataview.stopEditing();
            } else if (event.target.className === 'cancel') {
                this.options.dataview.cancelEditing();
            }
        }
    }

    handleKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.defaultPrevented || !document.activeElement) {
            return;
        }


        if (event.srcElement.value.length > this.maxLength) {
            event.srcElement.value = event.srcElement.value.substring(0, this.maxLength);

        }
        const key = event.key || event.keyCode;
        if (key === 'Enter' || key === 13) {
            if (document.activeElement.className === 'save') {
                event.stopPropagation();
                this.options.dataview.stopEditing();
            } else if (document.activeElement.className === 'cancel') {
                event.stopPropagation();
                this.options.dataview.cancelEditing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Angular has no idea how to resolve `options: any` in your constructor. What efforts have you made to configure dependency injection here? Where should they be injected from? Please add code to show where the options you want to inject are configured.

Comment: what is the source of "options"?

Comment: options is coming from a javascript control, spreadJS, that does not support Angular

Comment: there is angular option for spreadJS `https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v13/online/angular.html `. Is there reason not to use it?

Comment: Would it be possible to instead of adding it into the constructor and expecting DI to pick up something, to instead just import it like you import anything else? You'd have to get this JS code into your codebase, but it may be possible. After all, angular is a JS framework, so you should be able ta add in any TS/JS code classes. Maybe you can do some magic and make it available via npm, and reference it accordingly? Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is pointed out by Kurt Hamilton in the comments, a component's initialization is handled by Angular's injection system unless you do it explicitly. So, Angular has to know what `options` is. You can simply show Angular what needs to be used as `options`:

in your app.module.ts provide the `options` object by specifying it's value

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
  {provide: 'myoptions', useValue: {a: 'some option', b: 'some other option'}}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Inject the `options` with the injection key you specified.

```
  constructor(@Inject('myoptions') options) {

  }
```

This is actually what you do if you need to have access to that same `options` object throughout the module or application. However if the options will change for each different `TextAreaComponent` you have, then you should pass it as an `@Input`. That way you will be able to change the options dynamically.

You can find the instructions for `@Input` at angular.io: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: thanks for the response.  This component is to extend a javascript vendor dataview component that doesnt support angular.  options contains the dataview and values.  So I am not sure injecting it would work.  I tried the input as well

Answer (score 0):

In TextAreaComponent Decorator selector for this component is missing. There should be a selector for the component.